Netplan doesn't set static IP after upgrade 20.04 -> 22.04
I'm trying to set the static IP of a network interface on a server that has just upgraded its distro from 20.04 to 22.04. Here is the netplan /etc/netplan/80_netplan_netcfg.yaml.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [ 169.254.20.1/16 ]

The command sudo netplan apply doesn't seem to be able to assign the static IP to eno3 anymore. Here's the output of ip a:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:f2:c4:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp4s0f0
    inet6 2401:fa00:480:4029:aaa1:59ff:fef2:c45d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591429sec preferred_lft 604229sec
    inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:fef2:c45d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I've tried manually setting the static ip using ip a add 169.254.20.1/16 dev eno3 which initially succeeds in assigning the ip address, but somehow gets unassigned after a period of time. I'm not sure if some background process would be responsible for this, but ideally I would be able to do this with netplan.
I've been scratching my head all day about this, so any help would be appreciated!

Sorry, that was a typo. Edited the netplan to reflect what it is on the machine.

It looks like you're trying to use an IPv4 link-local address? it may be necessary to enable that explicitly - see for example Server 18.04: netplan and link-local addressing. The link in the accepted answer is broken, but there's some documentation here

Thanks for the tip - after configuring w/ that link-local attribute, I see that eno3 gets configured with a random IP - 169.254.22.45. Checking the journalctl logs, it shows eno3: Cannot configure requested address 169.254.20.1, as an address conflict was detected and eno3: Cannot configure requested address 169.254.20.2, as an address conflict was detected.  At at loss as to why networkd decided to try more addresses than what was specified and why it continued to configure with a completely different static IP.

After a reboot, the IP even changed to 169.254.251.244/16. I'm guessing that networkd is trying to configure to 169.254.20.1/16 and failing due to conflict. Then it picks a random available IP in the given link-local range.

I suspect that's just a pitfall of trying to assign a static address within the link-local pool - it would be more usual to assign static IPv4 addresses from your normal private LAN address space (192.168.x.y) and "reserve" those addresses on the router (i.e. make them unavailable for DHCP)

You could use
sudo netplan try

and
sudo netplan --debug apply

to find any errors.
Sometimes
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd

might also help to solve the problem.

First two commands didn't resolve the issue or provide any more info.
I ran
sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd before restarting the daemon and found this line - is there a way to get more debug info?
Apr 26 00:55:52 localhost systemd-networkd[764]: eno3: Failed
Restarting the daemon also didn't resolve the issue.

Debug gives you the hint. There is no eno3 device available!

You can also look in journald to get more details.

Okay, getting somewhere - looking in the journal, I found this error line: eno3: Cannot configure requested address 169.254.20.1, as an address conflict was detected. So I then tried to set the static ip to 169.254.20.2 and got the same error as before. At a last ditch, I tried 169.254.20.3, which worked! Now the question is, why was there an address conflict for the first 2 addresses? AFAIK those IPs were not in use.

IP addresses from 169.254.0.0 to 169.254.255.255. have a special meaning. This range is designated for Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA). Devices use an IP address from this range when they are configured to obtain an IP automatically, and no DHCP server is available to provide an IP address. May be another device was using this address.

That IP Address Range can also indicate a hardware failure.  Normal operating procedure is not to use them in order to help identify such failures.  If a DHCP server is available and attempts to hand out an address and fails, an address in the APiPA pool is chosen and assigned.
